# Trigger a range changing in GUIQwt Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwt

I have a PyQt5 application written in Python programming language. I use GUIQwt for graph drawing, and I implemented a method to add ranges to the CurveDialog manually in the application.

I would like to have an event to store the new values of the range in my CSV file if the range has changed. So I have two problems here. First, to trigger the range changing, and sceondly, to get back the values of the range if that happens.

I did not finnd any solutions for this on the internet, so was not able to try anything. I would appriciate any idea, lead for me to find the possible solution.

Thank you!